# transplant_class.<locals>.C) ... ERROR in python

Tags: python, docker, teamcity

I am running python suite using nosetests(nose==1.3.7,nose-testconfig==0.10)
 framework with pythom3.5.2, recently started facing issue in running suite. This error comes the beginning of every test folder. for example i have below folder structure:

```
DIR
---SUBDIR_1
------test_1
------test_2
---SUBDIR_2
------test_1
------test_2
```

when test start there is no error , runs SUBDIR1 testcases successfully but when starting SUBDIR2 then error comes. And this is being repetitive for all subfolders.

ERROR is:

```
> "__init__ (base.tests.aabc_service.test_testname.transplant_class.<locals>.C)
> ... ERROR"
```

Same set of test running fine at local with same folder and infra.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I had this issue when I subclassed an `attr` (nose.attr) decorated class.